# Client socket connection through a specified file in c language

Tags: c, linux, sockets

This is a python socket connection code from [MBDyn](https://www.mbdyn.org/) tutorial.

```
# create input socket (2 double: x, x_prime)
s_in = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
s_in.connect("./mbdyn.body.sock");
s_in_bufsize = 2*8

# create output socket (1 double: f)
s_out = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
s_out.connect("./mbdyn.spring.sock");
s_out_bufsize = 8
```

I want to understand how can I use

```
s_out.connect("./mbdyn.spring.sock");
```

way of connecting a file in c code as well.

```
connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))
```

How do I specify the file in the above `c` style code which act as the socket similarly like python?

Would the solution be something like

```
sock = fopen(...);//socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `AF_INET`, you need to use `AF_UNIX`, just as in your Python code.  Your system probably has a man page for `unix`, including examples.  Mine includes something like the following (paraphrasing: I've omitted the error checking):

> ```
>        struct sockaddr_un name;
>        memset(&name, 0, sizeof name);
>
>        /* Bind socket to socket name. */
>        name.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
>        strncpy(name.sun_path, SOCKET_NAME, sizeof name.sun_path - 1);
>
>        bind(connection_socket, (const struct sockaddr*)&name, sizeof name);
> ```

Note that the `sun_path` member of `struct sockaddr_un` is much smaller than `PATH_MAX` chars, so you're constrained as to where the socket inode should live.

Obviously you don't use `fopen()` - the `f` means "file".